# Getting error on compiling newlib

Tags: arm, toolchain

I am trying to build a arm toolchain from scratch.

I am referring to this site.

http://www.nixit.co.uk/cortex-m3-mac-1

Followed all the instructions carefully. Everything went well till newlib compilation. I am getting strange error.

/bin/bash: arm-none-eabi-cc: command not found

So I checked the Makefile
there is a line in makefile. There is a directive related to arm-none-eabi-cc

```
# -----------------------------------------------
# Programs producing files for the TARGET machine
# -----------------------------------------------

AR_FOR_TARGET=arm-none-eabi-ar
AS_FOR_TARGET=arm-none-eabi-as
CC_FOR_TARGET=$(STAGE_CC_WRAPPER) arm-none-eabi-cc

# If GCC_FOR_TARGET is not overriden on the command line, then this
# variable is passed down to the gcc Makefile, where it is used to
# build libgcc2.a.  We define it here so that it can itself be
# overridden on the command line.
GCC_FOR_TARGET=$(STAGE_CC_WRAPPER) arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

I checked the /usr/arm/bin directory. So i do find arm-none-eabi tools, but not **arm-none-eabi-cc**

```
arm-none-eabi-ld       arm-none-eabi-readelf
arm-none-eabi-ar         arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.4.3  arm-none-eabi-nm       arm-none-eabi-size
arm-none-eabi-as         **arm-none-eabi-gcc**
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing arm-none-eabi-cc in the Makefile with arm-none-eabi-gcc, or symlinking arm-none-eabi-cc to arm-none-eabi-gcc.

Comment: things moved ahead. Lets see what happens if the toolchain is able to compile the code correctly.